# PHP simple html dom parser div id with variable

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am new with PHP and i have a little problem.
How can I search with variable with simple html dom parser? My  id is "ti" and there are several same named divs. I only need the first one. The code works if i put ti instead of `$variable` to code.

thanks!

```
<?php

$variable = "ti"

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://myurl.here');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=$variable]', 0);
if ($ret) {
    echo $ret->innertext; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double quotation marks (i.e. `"` instead of `'`) to embed variables in PHP strings, like this:

```
$ret = $html->find("div[id=$variable]", 0);
```